# Von Neumann Inequality in Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

It is known that the only Banach space that satisfies the von-Neumann inequality is the Hilbert space:

**Theorem** (see e.g. Pisier, "Similarity Problems and Completely Bounded Maps", p 27) For a Banach space $F$ the following conditions are equivalent:

- for every linear operator $T$ on $F$ with $\|T\|\le 1$ and any algebraic polynomial $p$ we have $\|p(T)\|\le\sup_{|z|<1}|p(z)|$;
- $F$ is isometric to a Hilbert space.

If we allow $F$ to be merely isomorphic to a Hilbert space, the norm on $L(F)$ is replaced with an equivalent one and we get the following weaker von-Neumann inequality:

- There is $C>0$ such that for every linear operator $T$ on $F$ with $\|T\|\le 1$ and any algebraic polynomial $p$ we have $\|p(T)\|\le C\sup_{|z|<1}|p(z)|$.

> What are the Banach spaces for which the weaker von-Neumann inequality holds?

Clearly, if the inequality holds for $F$ it holds for any isomorphic space, and so it is not a geometric property. Could it be an isomorphic characterization of Hilbert spaces? Or perhaps, something like super reflexivity would imply this property? Or maybe it just holds for all Banach spaces?

Comment: I am almost certain that it doesn't hold for $F=\ell^1$, and I have a suspicion that it won't hold for $\ell^p$ for $p\neq 2$

Comment: Small remark: If the weaker von Neumann inequality holds on a Banach space $F$; then every linear contraction on $F$ admits a $A(D)$-functional calculus (where $A(D)$ denotes the disk algebra). This seems to be a rather strong property.

Comment: I have just taken a quick look at the proof in Pisier's book (the result is attributed to Foias) and I wonder if one could follow the argument, replacing $1$ by $C$ where necessary, to end up with a purely Banach-space condition on the two-dimensional real subspaces of $F$. Have you checked if this works? It would then reduce the problem to a question about Banach space geometry.

Comment: @YemonChoi yes, I thought about it, but I don't know what to do with the condition the condition that there is $C$ such that $\frac{\|y-\lambda x\|}{\|x-\overline{\lambda} y\|}\le C$, if $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$.

Comment: This paper seems to be closely related [On polynomialy bounded operators acting on Banach spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123605001266). At least it gives examples of a space on which the implication won't hold.

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician thank you! I was aware of this paper, but I guess the relevant part is contained in the second paragraph. This gives a counterexample in the class of general Banach spaces, but does not help with a characterization